# Vue 3 - TS - Vuetify 3.1.2 type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am developing an application using **Vue 3 (3.2.45)**, **Typescript (4.9.4)** and **Vuetify (3.1.2)**.

Many of the **Vuetify** components require that you pass **props** that indicate things like default style, location, or some v-model to show/hide the component. Sometimes, whenever I pass the prop (as specified in their documentation) the compiler gives me the following error:

`Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'`

Boolean is just an example, it just says whatever type I try to pass to v-model. The following code is an example that gives the error:

```
<template>
  <div class="main-content">
    <h2>Home</h2>
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog"
    >
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-btn
          color="primary"
          v-bind="props"
        >
          Open Dialog
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" block @click="dialog = false">Close Dialog</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";
const dialog = ref(false);
</script>
```

In this case, the **v-dialog** component from **Vuetify** requires a v-model that is typed as **boolean** per their own documentation (https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-dialog/).

As you can see here, I get an error on the **v-model**:

[image: Screenshot of error showing v-model underlined with red]

The code **still works** but it bugs me that my compiler complains and shows files with this kind of "error" red in my workspace.

This just happened (so far) with Vuetify components. The ones I create and type in my own do not show this behaviour.

I don't know if there's a way I can configure my text editor (vs-code) to just ignore this warning or whether I'm doing something wrong that triggers the error.

Comment: I have a project with almost the same setup as you (Vuetify 3.0.7 and Typescript 4.7.4), and vscode infers the property correctly: `(property) modelValue?: boolean | undefined`. Do you use [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar)?

Comment: In my case if I don't pass any value to v-model it infers its type as `any` but if I pass the boolean then it infers it as `boolean` which is kind of weird. I do use **Volar**. Did you configure anything differently besides Volar? Like any specific typescript plug-in?

Comment: Are you using takedown mode?

Comment: @RussDeneychuk nope. And I tried disabling the Typescript Vue Plugin, since it was recommended, and I still get the error.

Comment: Just the builtins. Thought I had [takeover mode](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode) enabled, but it wasn't (and it seems to give the same result). Also, I don't have the discouraged "Typescript Vue Plugin", just regular "Vue Language Features". Updated Vuetify to 3.1.2, same result.

Answer (score 1):

**Ref<boolean> !== boolean**

I found out, that when you use

```js
    <v-dialog
      v-model="dialog.value"
    >
```

It compiles just fine.

I do not know why, but in some places, Vuetify explicitly asks for primitives instead of Refs, so when passing `dialog.value`, you pass the primitive boolean instead of the ref.

Answer (score 0):

try to declare the model like this `let dialog = ref(false)` and during event try `const eventDialog = () => { dialog.value = false; }`